# Printing an RTF file using Printdialog in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, rtf, printdocument, printdialog

I have this code:

```
Private printDocument1 As New PrintDocument()
Private stringToPrint As String

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Dim docName As String = "print_doc.rtf"
    Dim docPath As String = fsPathPrintDoc
    printDocument1.DocumentName = docName
    Dim stream As New FileStream(docPath + docName, FileMode.Open)
    Try
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
        Try
            stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Finally
            reader.Dispose()
        End Try
    Finally
        stream.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and I do the printing using:

```
ReadFile()
printDocument1.Print()
```

I want to print a rtf file using a VB.NET `printdialog.show()`, because in want to choose specific printers for printing, but my above code i dont have any idea, how i can embed `printdialog` here.

This is required because i want to print that file using printers available on different systems using network. Now all these available printers are available for me in print dialog, what i want is to simply print a particular file in my drive using `printdialog()`

Also, I tried to find a possibility to print a file using `printdialog` and `printdocument` but unfortunately failed.

**Edit:**

I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx but it does not includes `printdialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign your PrintDocument to the [PrintDialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx) [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.document.aspx) Property, it will then add the selected printer to your Document. You then print the Document as normal.

```
PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True 
PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = True 
PrintDialog1.Document = printDocument1 'Assign your Document here

Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()

If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
    printDocument1.Print()
End If
```

Comment: Because when i type `PrintDialog1.Document = "C:\temp.rtf"` it shows me Error `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument'.`

Comment: You handle the printing the same way, pass the print document that you created earlier to the print dialog, then once you have selected the printer then print it.